# How do I add domains to certificate

Tags: security-certificate

I just installed a dedi. I got a self signed certificate to maindomain.com

Then I want to access childdomain.com/cpanel

The certificate is for the main domain on the server. I tried to access cPanel on another domain under that main domain.

So of course internet explorer complained. Well, how can my main domain issue a certificate for the child domain?

Comment: Does your _self_ signed certificate not generate a browser warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only apply one domain per certificate.

If you're looking to make a self-signed certificate, this site will help you out: http://www.selfsignedcertificate.com/

Comment: And how do I do so? How do I generate another certificate for this new domain?

Comment: The same way you generated the first one. Each domain you want a certificate for will need a unique IP address.

Comment: I do not generate the first one it's already there.

Comment: You have to get a certificate issued by a certificate authority. Your hosting provider should have information on this.

Comment: I don't need others to trust the certificate. I trust it. It's my site.

Comment: Then you don't understand how certificates work.

Comment: How do I be my own certificate authority? I trust my self.

Comment: You can't really be your own certificate authority, but you can self sign a certificate. That will work for the purposes you seem to want. Link added to the answer.